Parsing JSON data from a php server on a esp32
so i have a problem with parsing the JSON data that i recive as payload from a php server.
The server insert a order_pending row in order_pending table when i press a order button and it fills it with an id and some others parameters.
The php code is:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $api_key = test_input($_GET["api_key"]);
    if($api_key == $api_key_value) { 
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
    
        
        $sql = "SELECT locker_id,quantity_ordered,quantity,payload FROM orders_pending WHERE order_id=(SELECT MIN(order_id) FROM orders_pending WHERE locker_id!=404)";
        $data=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
        $test = $row["locker_id"]; 
        if($test==NULL)
        {
            $row["locker_id"]="404";
        }
        ob_clean();
        header_remove();
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($row);
    
        $conn->close();
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong API Key provided.";
    }

}
else {
    echo "No data posted with HTTP POST.";
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


and the esp32 code is:
String checkPendingOrder()
{
  int lockerid = 0;
  String payload;
  

   //Check WiFi connection status
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    WiFiClient *client = new WiFiClient;
    //client->setInsecure(); //don't use SSL certificate
    HTTPClient http;
 
    // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
    String serverPath = serverName + "?api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";
    http.useHTTP10(true);
    http.setTimeout(10000);
    http.begin(serverPath.c_str());
 
    // Specify content-type header
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 
    // Send HTTP GET request
    int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
    //payload => variable which contains info about the lockers in DB
    String payload = http.getString();

if (httpResponseCode > 0) 
    {
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code check: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    else 
    {
      Serial.print("Error check code check: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    http.end();
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
  }
  
    return payload;}

void loop() 
{
  
  //inputs for locker feedback
  /*
  int l1 = digitalRead(lock1);
  int l2 = digitalRead(lock2);
  */

  //the locker id from the DB is assigned to the int variable lockerid
  //JsonDocument data= checkPendingOrder();
  //int lockerid=data["locker_id"].as<int>();
  //serializeJsonPretty(data,Serial);
 // scale.power_up();
  String data =checkPendingOrder();
  JsonDocument doc;
  deserializeJson(doc,data);
  int lockerid=doc["locker_id"];}

the output i get is allways:
HTTP Response code check: 500
0

i want to know if i send correct the json array or if i parsed correct?

A 500 error suggests that the PHP code crashed. Make sure you've got PHP error logging enabled, then test the code again, and check the PHP log to see what went wrong. I notice that $api_key_value doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the code you've shown, so maybe it's failing because of that (when you try to compare it to $api_key).

P.S. Your PHP only sometimes returns JSON (i.e. only when everything is successful). That's a bad idea- those random error messages you're echoing should be wrapped in an object and encoded as JSON with a predictable structure, so that the calling code can parse them and find the error message if one exists. Whereas, if you send back non-JSON, the caller won't be able to parse it and may crash

P.P.S. Your test_input function is completely nonsenical junk, and is a commonly-found cargo-cult function which supposedly "sanitises" data (whatever that really means). In fact it's far more likely to accidentally modify the data for no good reason. It doesn't protect against SQL injection, it may trim or change data without good cause, and it HTML-encodes it at a time when the data isn't being used in a HTML document, which is pointless and potentially destructive. Just get rid of that function completely please, it's useless and harmful.

http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); doesn't make any sense in a GET request, because no request body is being sent, therefore there is no content! You'd use that Content-Type when submitting a POST request containing some form data.

Also in the esp code, for the purposes of debugging this problem, you should try to output data directly (before you try to deserialise it as JSON) in case - as I mentioned earlier - the response contains something which isn't JSON

Your PHP code doesn't have any syntax errors. That would mean that the error is somewhere else. As @ADyson mentioned, if you haven't already, enable error reporting. A couple of notes. 1) I see that you're using uppercase names for your DB connection parameter variables. Are they really variables, or are they constants? 2) Does your query work if you execute it via phpMyAdmin (for example)? 3) Why are you closing your connection with $conn->close() if , earlier in your code, you're using procedural style (i.e. mysqli_query(...), mysqli_fetch_assoc(...)?

the api key is sett but i didn't put the whole code in it, i just want to know if the sentence that i wrote for json data transfer and parseing it is correct

1)they are variables 2)yes it work, before this code i only access the locker_id and forward it succesfully to the esp32 and evreything worked fine,but after i tried to forward multiple data in a json object it didnt work thats why i wanted to know if the code i used for forwarding and parseing was correct written 3) because this code is called often and i want to have a new connection, i thought this is the way it should be

thats what i want to know ADyson "wrapped in an object and encoded as JSON with a predictable structure" i tried verious method but i got allways as output parsed 0 when i print lockerid=doc["locker_id"], null when i print the whole json object and nothing whne i try to print the payload as string

This question is not answerable without some basic debugging information. When you doing Client/Server solution, it is important to make sure one side work before trying to do the other side of the code. Test your server with linux curl command or use app such as postman to ensure the server work first. HTTP 500 usually means that the database unable to retriever whatever requested. Print out $data or $row, and what do you see?

i solve it, the problem was that i didnt declare $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data), i just put it in the while statment :)), but with this ocasion i learned to use postman :)
